# can perform some operations but not all on c# calculator?

Tags: c#

So far, my addition and subtraction work. But, my multiplication and division do not. This is because the first two numbers I put in get added and them the operation is done. Such as, if 9 * 9 + 3 should be 84, it is 21 on my calculator. That is because it is taking 9+9 + 3; as it only sees the last operator. 
I have absolutely no idea how to fix this. Is there any helpful insight?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    double num2;
    double num1;
    string c;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text + btn0.Text;
    }

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text + btn1.Text;
    }

    private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text + btn2.Text;
    }

    private void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text + btn3.Text;
    }

    private void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text + btn4.Text;
    }

    private void btn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text + btn5.Text;
    }

    private void btn6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text + btn6.Text;
    }

    private void btn7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text + btn7.Text;
    }

    private void btn8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text + btn8.Text;
    }

    private void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text + btn9.Text;
    }

    private void btnDecimal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!txtBox.Text.Contains('.'))
            txtBox.Text += '.';
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Clear();
    }

    private void btnAddition_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num1 = num1 + double.Parse(txtBox.Text);
        c = "+";
        txtBox.Clear();
    }

    private void btnSubtraction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num1 = num1 + double.Parse(txtBox.Text);
        c = "-";
        txtBox.Clear();
    }

    private void btnMultiplication_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num1 = num1 + double.Parse(txtBox.Text);
        c = "*";
        txtBox.Clear();
    }

    private void btnDivision_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num1 = num1 + double.Parse(txtBox.Text);
        c = "/";
        txtBox.Clear();
    }
    private void btnEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        double result;

        num2 = double.Parse(txtBox.Text);

        switch (c)
        {
            case "+":
                result = num1 + num2;
                txtBox.Text = result.ToString();
                num1 = 0;
                break;
            case "-":
                result = num1 - num2;
                txtBox.Text = result.ToString();
                num1 = 0;
                break;
            case "*":
                result = num1 * num2;
                txtBox.Text = result.ToString();
                num1 = 0;
                break;
            case "/":
                if (num2 != 0)
            {
                result = num1 / num2;
                txtBox.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                txtBox.Text = "You can't divide by zero... sign up for Math 100 please =)";
            }
            break;
            default:
                result = 0;
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you consider an off the wall number?

Comment: Off the wall was incorrect for me to use. Actually, incorrect is the term I should have said.

Comment: Do you know about the `+=` operator. Makes the code more readable to have `txtBox.Text += btn2.Text;`

Comment: Check your method btnMultiplication_Click here you are doing num1 = num1 + double.Parse(txtBox.Text); does it sound right to you ? and same for division.

Comment: No it does not. But when changed to * it still does not operate correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the previous operation before overwriting it with a new one:

```
private void btnAddition_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    num2 = double.Parse(txtBox.Text);
    num1 = calc(num1, num2, c);
    c = "+";
    txtBox.Clear();
}
```

where calc does the operation that you do on "=" now.

Comment: 4 + 6 - 2 =, will give you 4.

Comment: @Jonie No.  Because result gets written back to txtBox after each operator.

Comment: where does it do that? you press btnAddition, it sets num1, sets c, and clears your textbox.

Comment: I want them written back to txtBox so I can always see what I clicked.

Comment: Jonie is correct.  You are forgetting the first operation when you do a second one.

Comment: 4+6-2 gives you 8, as it is set up how I had it.

Comment: @stark I do not understand what calc does. I understand that my first number and second number are being added and then the operation is being performed. That is why my * and / are messed up. (such as + does not matter and - works as well for the most part).

Comment: It's a subroutine that does what is in your switch statement.

Comment: @stark Dang! I guess I need to get on MSDN or somewhere and read because I have not heard of subroutines.

Comment: I am assuming it is a method. I wrote one and it compiled yet gives me the answer of 0 for everything

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

Look at your `num1` variable every time after you click an operator other than equal. Say I start with 6*4-3. I press 6, then *. At this point num1 now becomes 6. Press 4 and - next. Now 4 is Added to Num1 making 10. Then 3 and equal is pressed, which probably gave you 7.

Second issue:
c is being overridden every time you press a different operator such as + or minus.

Solutions:

1) You could make an infix parser or

2) Modify your code to something as follow (giving example for subtraction)

```
private void btnSubtraction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Equals()
    c = "-";
    txtBox.Clear();
}

private void btnEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Equals();
    txtBox.Text = Result.ToString();
    result = 0;
}

private void Equals()
{
    if (!double.TryParse(txtBox.Text, out num2)) return;

    switch (c)
    {
        case "+":
            result = result + num2;
            break;
        case "-":
            result = result - num2;
            break;
        case "*":
            result = result * num2;
            break;
        case "/":
            result = result / num2;
            break;
        default:
            result = num2;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is num1. Everytime you do an opperation you are just adding num1 with the value of the text box.

So I think when you press the buttons: `6*4-3=` you should get 21, but you are acrually getting 7

This is because num1 is being added when you press * and - buttons, so you end up doing 6+4-3 = 7.

You need to change `btnMultiplication_Click` to something like:

```
private void btnMultiplication_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    num1 = num1 * double.Parse(txtBox.Text);
    c = "*";
    txtBox.Clear();
}
```

and something similar for divide and subtract. I think subtract only works in your example because it's the last thing you do and the equals button handles it correctly.

I haven't tested this out but I think that's your problem

Comment: You forget that he has `num1` set to 0 at the start, so doing `num1 * double.Parse()` would get you 0 again.

Comment: Good point. Maybe that is why the original was adding numbers instead of mulitplying?

Comment: Could be. Just off the top of my head, I would probably set a boolean to check if it's the first number of the input. Something like `if (isFirstInput) { num1 = double.Parse(txtBox.Text); isFirstInput = false } else { num1 = num1 * double.Parse(txtBox.Text); }`

Comment: @Greg the math you said I get is correct. 6*4-3=7 on this calculator. But I thought setting num1 = 0; is just a default?

Comment: You need to set num1 = 0 to start with, but you can't just add the numbers together. I think @Stark's answer is the best one here. Because you are adding to num1 everytime, you are never actually doing the multiply. So you end up with 6+4-3 instead of 6*4-3. Only the last operation is actually done correctly, all others are just additions. Ichabod Clay's comment above shows why my suggestion won't work either. Go with Stark's answer

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is that you're doing, for every operator:

`num1 = num1 + double.Parse(txtBox.Text);`

and that's wrong, because you're only adding every number you write in your calculator, except the last one, which is calculated correctly, due to `btnEquals_Click`.
In fact you check what operator you're using only when "=" is pressed, you have to do that for every operator you choose.

Answer (score 0):

When any operation (+, -, /, *, =) is performed, the existing state (including the last operation) should be evaluated and replaces your first number, operation and second number.

Look at your criteria, here's the state before/after each action:

- 2+2+2= 6

  - 2+

    - before: firstNumber=0 (default), operation="+" (default, hidden), secondNumber=2
    - after: firstNumber=2 (calc 0+2), operation="+", secondNumber=empty (awaiting input)
  - 2+2+

    - before: firstNumber=2, operation="+", secondNumber=2
    - after: firstNumber=4(calc 2+2), operation="+", secondNumber=empty (awaiting input)
  - 2+2+2=

    - before: 4 + 2
    - after: 6 + (empty)
- 2+3-1= 4

  - 2+

    - before: 0(default) +(default) 2
    - after: 2 + (empty)
  - 2+3-

    - before: 2 + 3
    - after: 5 - (empty)
  - 2+3-1=

    - before: 5 - 1
    - after: 4 +(inferred) (empty)
- 6*4-3= 21

  - 6*

    - before: 0(default) +(default) 6
    - after: 6 * (empty)
  - 6*4-

    - before: 6 * 4
    - after: 24 - (empty)
  - 6*4-3=

    - before: 24 - 3
    - after: 21 +(inferred) (empty)

Does that make more sense?

Also to follow standard calculator conventions you might want to consider allowing people to change the operation if the 2nd number is currently empty, e.g.

given this sequence:

- 6*4=-3= - perform 6*4 and see result ("="), then subtract 3 from that and show that result ("=")

  - 6*

    - before: 0(default) +(default) 6 -> 6 * (empty)
  - 6*4=: 6 * 4

    - after: 24 +(inferred) (empty)
  - 6*4=-

    - before: 24 + (empty)
    - after **special case**: 24 - (empty)
  - 6*4=-3=

    - before: 24 - 3
    - after: 21 +(inferred) (empty)

**UPDATE:**
To put this in terms of your code, you would need to change the +, -, /, * and = buttons to all work the same way. That is, take `num1`, `c` and the current value of `double.Parse(txtBox.Text)`, perform that operation then update based on the new operation.

```
// is the current txtBox value new, so will be cleared and allow op change
private bool isNew = true;
// change this to default to +
string c = "+";
double num1 = 0;

private void Evaluate(string newOperand)
{
    if (isNew)
    {
        // just update the operand, don't perform an evaluate
        c = newOperand;
        return;
    }

    double num2 = double.Parse(txtBox.Text);
    switch (c)
    {
        case "+":
            num1 = num1 + num2;
            break;
        // etc for -, /, *

        // for "="
        default:
            num1 = num1 + num2;
            break;
    }
    isNew = true;
    c = newOperand;
}

// this can be assigned as the handler for buttons 0 - 9
public void btnNumber_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    txtBox.Text += button.Text;
    isNew = false;
}

// this can be assigned as the event handler for all operations: +, -, /, *, =
public void btnOperation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    Evaluate(button.Text);
}
```

I have changed the whole purpose of `num1` from the way you did it, so it is now the firstNumber as in my examples above.

You might want to add a clear all that will reset `num1` to 0 and `c` to +. You could also do this in your existing `btnClear_Click` by detecting a 2nd press, like many calculators do:

```
public void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isNew)
    {
        num1 = 0;
        c = "";
        // text box should already be empty
    }
    else
    {
        isNew = true;
        txtBox.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Then why is 2 + 3 * 2 = 10 but 10 / 2 + 3 = 11?

Comment: 10/2+3 will work out to 8. I'm not sure what you mean? It evaluates to 0+10 = 10 (before/after "/" button), 10/2 = 5 (before/after "+" button), 5 + 3 = 8 (before/after "=" button).